# How do I extend my backgrounds beyond my grid - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to bootstrap and I having trouble making my site do what I want it to. Hopefully someone can steer me in the right direction.

I used bootstrap to make a nice responsive grid for my site within a container. The problem I am having is that I would like my backgrounds (different backgrounds in different sections) to fill browser window while the page content stays at 1170px max-width. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course. adding your own css is not that bad but make sure your css is in last (e.g , )
do this in your background telling your div

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0;left:0;background-image: url('img/urbg.png');">
```

dont box here. experiment, play and explore. bootstrap is boxed dont get TRAP with BOOTSTRAP. its cool but you need to know when to handle design with image background. [see this](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-grayscale/)

Comment: I understand what you mean about not getting trapped in bootstrap. From my first look I think the link you sent me is going to be very helpful. I appreciate it!